I made a Betty Crocker cake mix with oil instead of butter - how to fix it?
I used 1/3 cup of oil instead of 1/3 cup of butter in a Betty Crocker cake mix! How can I fix this?

And how was it?

Well, there's certainly no way to remove the oil from the batter. And you shouldn't add butter at this point, because then there'll be too much oil/butter overall.
So you have two options: Bake it and hope for the best, or throw it out and start over. Personally I'd go with the first one. The final texture may be a bit greasy, but I don't think it'll be unacceptably so.

One could possibly try to improve the batter by adding some water and flower and sugar.

+1 I've done this intentionally (read: too lazy to use butter) many times and it works out okay. It may not be the best cake you've ever had but it's better than no cake.

It's not a problem! Next time you can intentionally substitute oil for butter - just use a tad less oil ( 1/4 cup less for every cup) and it won't be greasy! They will still taste moist and delicious!

And if it comes out as a less than ideal cake, you can always put a scoop of ice cream or similar on it to mask its imperfections.  Or use it in a triffle, bread pudding (don't add any sugar to the custard) or similar

@suse Honestly, for box cakes, I prefer to make them with vegetable oil.  But I don't actually like cake all that much, and find the moister, tending-toward-pudding texture to be much more likable.

I've seen multiple times the suggest for other cake mixes to replace oil with butter - I can only imagine if you can substitute one way, doing so the other shouldn't be too big of an issue (and other comments/answers seem to agree).

Butter is typically around 80%+ fat and 16%+ water, with the remainder being other miscellaneous bits and bobbles (milk solids, salt, etc).  If you add oil instead of butter, the difference is going to be that you have added a little bit of extra fat, and reduced the amount of water in the recipe by a small amount.  I expect this to have two major effects on the final outcome:

the cake may come out a little bit greasier or oiler than you expect (since the oil is liquid at room temperature, and butter is not), and

the cake my not get the same rise you expect—box cakes tend to rely on some chemical leavening (e.g. baking powder) and some steam to rise; since you have reduced the amount of water in the recipe, there may be less steam to produce lift.


I would expect both of these effects to be fairly minor.  You have essentially reduced the liquid and increased the fat by about a tablespoon.  The cake will probably be just fine—boxed cake mixes are generally calibrated to be fairly hard to mess up too badly.

The main difference between oil and butter in baked goods is how it behaves before and after baking, not during. The greasiness, if present, would have nothing to do with the marginally higher fat content, but with the fact that vegetable oil is liquid at room temperature and butter is not.

@Sneftel I thought that was implicit, and was trying not to step on your answer.  I've made a small edit.

I just looked at a sunflower oil label. Looks like it has at 8% water as well.

When I read this, I was immediately reminded of my mother's tale of how her wedding cake, in 1946, was baked using 'liquid paraffin' (a highly refined mineral oil, not to be confused with kerosene) because most fats were rationed in the UK at that time.

Make cupcakes instead of a cake. Substituting oil makes your cake lighter and fluffier, so it won't be as strong (will tend to fall apart). Which is what you want for cupcakes and muffins, which is why cupcakes and muffin recipes often call for oil instead of butter.
If it's not a chocolate cake, you may miss the butter flavour. Add a little cinnamon or rum or whatever to punch up the flavour.
